# What role is needed to view policy compliance in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security, azure-rbac

I would like a user to have read only access to policy compliance if possible but I can't seem to figure out which permissions they need. I've looked over the policy permissions and they have read access on the policies but still are unable to read the compliance.

Comment: Compliance? What's the compliance in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your user needs policy insights access.